# Gradle 3.0.0 upgrade from gradle-experimental:0.9.3 errors

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

After upgrading to Android Studio 3.0 a project has been updated too, although I still retain a backup of it. I though I'd go along with upgrading from a very early version of the experimental gradle plugin to version 3.0.0 which I'm having lots of trouble with.

The top level gradle file looks to be absolutely fine I think.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.9.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The app gradle build file is the one I've been making a shed load of changes to. It currently complains about `cppFlags` with the error:

`Error:(25, 0) Could not find method cppFlags() for arguments [-std=c++11, -fexceptions, -Isrc/main/android/armeabi-v7a/include, -frtti, -O2] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkOptions.`

The changes so far to this gradle file are:

```
//apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

//model {
    android {
        buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
        compileSdkVersion 23

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 19

            ndk {
                def ffmpeg = "src/main/android/armeabi-v7a/include"

                moduleName = "ffplayer3jni"

                ldLibs "log", "android", "GLESv2", "dl", "EGL", "z",
                        "stdc++", "OpenSLES"

                //cppFlags.addAll("-std=c++11", "-fexceptions", '-I'+file(ffmpeg),
                //        "-D __cplusplus=201103L", "-frtti",
                //        "-D __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__", "-O2")

                cppFlags "-std=c++11", "-fexceptions", "-I${ffmpeg}", "-frtti", "-O2"

                stl "gnustl_static"

                //abiFilters.addAll("armeabi-v7a")
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
            }
        }
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.pro'))
        }
    }

    repositories {
        def loc = "src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/"

        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {

            libavutil {
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file(loc + "libavutil.so")
                }
            }

            libavcodec {
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file(loc + "libavcodec.so")
                }
            }

            libavformat {
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file(loc + "libavformat.so")
                }
            }

            libavfilter {
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file(loc + "libavfilter.so")
                }
            }

            libpostproc {
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file(loc + "libpostproc.so")
                }
            }

            libswresample {
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file(loc + "libswresample.so")
                }
            }

            libswscale {
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file(loc + "libswscale.so")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    android.sources {
        main {
            jni {
                dependencies {
                    library "libavformat" linkage "shared"
                    library "libavcodec" linkage "shared"
                    library "libavfilter" linkage "shared"
                    library "libavutil" linkage "shared"
                    library "libswscale" linkage "shared"
                    library "libswresample" linkage "shared"
                    library "libpostproc" linkage "shared"
                }
            }
        }
    }
//}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

The original gradle file still worked with Android Studio 2.3 even though it was using the old experimental plugin. This file is/was:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        def ffmpeg = "src/main/android/armeabi-v7a/include"

        buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
        compileSdkVersion 25

        defaultConfig.with {
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 19
        }

        ndk {
            moduleName = "ffplayer3jni"

            ldLibs.addAll("log", "android", "GLESv2", "dl", "atomic", "EGL",
                    "z", "stdc++", "OpenSLES")

            cppFlags.addAll("-std=c++11", "-fexceptions", '-I'+file(ffmpeg),
                    "-D __cplusplus=201103L", "-frtti",
                    "-D __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__", "-O2")
            CFlags.add('-I'+file(ffmpeg))

            stl = "gnustl_static"
            //stl = "stlport_shared"

            abiFilters.addAll("armeabi-v7a")
        }
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
        }
    }

    repositories {
        def loc = "src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/"

        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {

            libavutil {
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file(loc + "libavutil.so")
                }
            }

            libavcodec {
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file(loc + "libavcodec.so")
                }
            }

            libavformat {
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file(loc + "libavformat.so")
                }
            }

            libavfilter {
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file(loc + "libavfilter.so")
                }
            }

            libpostproc {
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file(loc + "libpostproc.so")
                }
            }

            libswresample {
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file(loc + "libswresample.so")
                }
            }

            libswscale {
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file(loc + "libswscale.so")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    android.sources {
        main {
            jni {
                dependencies {
                    library "libavformat" linkage "shared"
                    library "libavcodec" linkage "shared"
                    library "libavfilter" linkage "shared"
                    library "libavutil" linkage "shared"
                    library "libswscale" linkage "shared"
                    library "libswresample" linkage "shared"
                    library "libpostproc" linkage "shared"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

So my question is, what changes do I need to make in order to get this project working with the new gradle plugin in Android Studio 3.0?

As you can see, I have made some changes. Moved sections around and changed the options to eventually get through the gradle script, but now I am very stuck.

EDIT: I gave up in the end and created a new project from scratch in Android Studio 3.0.1. After much googling I managed to get all the native code, ffmpeg libraries and correct builds done.

Comment: Did you follow : http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental/migrate-to-stable ?

Comment: That only outlines the upgrade from 2.3 to the new build system. I'm going from 0.9.3 to 3.0.0. My fault for being reluctant so long ago. Considering creating a new project and copying everything over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I gave up in the end and created a new project from scratch in Android Studio 3.0.1. After much googling I managed to get all the native code, ffmpeg libraries and correct builds done.

Right, the concept of experimental plugin was very different. It tried to introduce an new groovy-based build system. Here you rely on established tools — cmake or Android.mk — to build the native libraries.